# save mouse clicks in java

Tags: java

I am trying to save the location of the mouse position-on a click.Then i need to analyze its motion to do a specific task.I used the mouseListener interface and when the user clicks the mouse i add the point of clicking to a point array.Then when a user clicks on a button,i tried loop through the array to analyze the motion but i get a null pointer exception at `if(points[i].x<points[i+1].x)`
Here is the code

```
Point points[] = new Point[2000];
int numPoints = 0;
void eventOutput(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e) {
  System.out.println(eventDescription+" X= "+e.getX()+" Y= "+e.getY());
  //xList.add(new Integer(e.getX()));
  //yList.add(new Integer(e.getY()));
  points[numPoints] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
  ++numPoints;        
}
for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++)
{
  System.out.println("In MOO "+points[i].x);
  if(points[i].x<points[i+1].x)
  {
    xInc=true;
    if(points[i].y<points[i+1].y)
    {
      yInc=true;
    }
    else if(points[i].y>points[i+1].y)
    {
      yDec=true;
    }
  }
  else if(points[i].x>points[i+1].x)
  {
    xDec=true;
    if(points[i].y<points[i+1].y)
    {
      yInc=true;
    }
    else if(points[i].y>points[i+1].y)
    {
      yDec=true;
    }}}}
```

Could anyone please help me about that.Thanks in advance

Comment: first, Your loop should stop at points.length-1 because you are using in the loop i+1. Second, are you sure you stored 2000 Point Objects in your array ?

Comment: @Amine No,i just discovered that,i`ll change it now. Thank you so much for pointing out that.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to loop over all of the array -- you only want to loop up to `numPoints`, since later entries are null, right? In fact, if you're going to compare an element with the next element, then you actually only want to loop up to `i < numPoints-1`, so that you have one more at the end to compare with.

Consider using a `List` like an `ArrayList` rather than an array -- it would be easier to avoid problems like this.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that an array is not the best solution. There is also nothing to prevent `numPoints` from exceeding 2000.

Comment: Yes you are right, but actually i was using ArrayList but i got the same problem so i changed it to Point array but i guess the problem was looping until 2000.Thank you so much,i`ll try it.

Answer (score 2):

you must iterate up to numPoints instead of points.length at

```
for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++)
```

points.length is total size of array, not the number of elements that contains.